# Array List Program With File Reading

Tags: java, file, arraylist, compiler-errors

I have created 2 classes, one is a driver class that executes the code and all methods are called from this class. The code needs to read the information from my file and store the data in an ArrayList of StudentScore (my other class). When i run my code, i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at StudentScore.toString(StudentScore.java:153)
    at ScoreDriver.main(ScoreDriver.java:37)
```

this is my driver class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class ScoreDriver extends StudentScore{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String fileName = "scores.txt";
     String line = null;
        ArrayList<Integer>studentIDNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();//Set student ID as an arraylist
        ArrayList<Integer>verbalScore = new ArrayList<Integer>();//Set verbal score as an arraylist
        ArrayList<Integer>mathScore = new ArrayList<Integer>();// Set math score as an arraylist


    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName); //Read from file 


    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",",-1);    
        if(values[0].length() > 1 )
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            studentIDNumber.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0])); // the first value is the ID number
            verbalScore.add(Integer.parseInt(values[1]));// Second value is verbal score
            mathScore.add(Integer.parseInt(values[2])); // third value is math score
        }   
    }   
    bufferedReader.close(); //Closing file
    StudentScore value = new StudentScore();// Instantiate what a student score is 
    value.setstudentIDNumber(studentIDNumber); // Includes a ID number, verbal score, math score and total score
    value.setverbalScore(verbalScore);
    value.setmathScore(mathScore);
    value.gettotalScore();  

    value.toString(15630);// Input any student ID number that you want to look up to check that students scores 

    System.out.println("The average Evidence-base Reading and Writing Score is: " + AverageVerbalScore());
    System.out.println("The average Math score is: " + AverageMathScore());
    System.out.println("The average combined score is: " + AverageCombinedScore());
    System.out.println("The total number of unique test-takers is: " + UniqueTest());

    value.HighestCombined(15630);// Input the student ID number to see what their best math score, verbal score and superscore is

    System.out.println("The highest Evidence-base Reading and Writing score is: " + HighestVerbal());
    System.out.println("The lowest Math score is: " + LowestMath());
}   
}
```

this is my other class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentScore 
{// Instantiate a Student's Score
private static ArrayList<Integer>studentIDNumber;
private static ArrayList<Integer>verbalScore;
private  static ArrayList<Integer>mathScore;
public static ArrayList<Integer>totalScore = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void setstudentIDNumber(ArrayList<Integer> value)// Setting a 
studentIDNumber
{
    this.studentIDNumber = value;
}
public void setverbalScore(ArrayList<Integer> value)//Setting a verbal 
score
    {
    this.verbalScore = value;
    }
public void setmathScore(ArrayList<Integer> value)// Setting a math 
score
    {
    this.mathScore = value;
    }
public void gettotalScore()// calculate total score
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < verbalScore.size(); i++) 
    {     
        int value = ((verbalScore.get(i) + mathScore.get(i))); // total 
score is the verbal and math combined
        totalScore.add((value)); //add value to total score 

        System.out.println(totalScore.get(i));
    }
}
public static int AverageVerbalScore()// Calculate average verbal score 
from the whole file 
{   
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < verbalScore.size(); i++)
        sum += verbalScore.get(i); 

    return sum/verbalScore.size();

    }

public static int AverageMathScore()//Calculate average math score from 
the whole file
{
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < mathScore.size(); i++)
    sum += mathScore.get(i);

return sum/mathScore.size();

}
public static int AverageCombinedScore()//Calculate average total Score 
from the whole file
{
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < totalScore.size(); i++)
    sum += totalScore.get(i);

return sum/totalScore.size();

}

public void HighestCombined(int studentID)//Method to find highest 
score of an inputed student ID number 
{
int rowNumber[]=new int[100];
int i = 0;
int bestTotalScore = 0;

    if(studentIDNumber.contains(studentID))
    {
        rowNumber[i] = studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID);

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {

            if(studentIDNumber.get(studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID) + j + 1 ) == studentID)
            {

                i++;
                rowNumber[i] = studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID) + j + 1;                  
            }   
        }
        for(i = 0; i < rowNumber.length; i++)   
        {
            if(rowNumber[i] >= 1 )  
            {
                if(totalScore.get(rowNumber[i]) > bestTotalScore)
                {
                    bestTotalScore = totalScore.get(rowNumber[i]);
                }                   
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("The highest superscore for student ID " + studentID + " is: " + bestTotalScore);
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Student ID does not exist");
    }   
 }

public static int HighestVerbal()// Highest verbal score method 
{
int highest = verbalScore.get(0);
for (int i  = 0; i < verbalScore.size(); i++)
{
    if (highest < verbalScore.get(i))
        highest = verbalScore.get(i);
}
return highest;
}
public static int LowestMath()//Lowest math score method 
{
int lowest = mathScore.get(0);
for(int i = 1; i < mathScore.size(); i++)
{
    if (mathScore.get(i) < lowest)
        lowest = mathScore.get(i);
}
return lowest;
}
public static int UniqueTest() //Method that compares each student ID 
to see how many times the student took the test
{
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < studentIDNumber.size()-1;i++)
{
    boolean found = false;

    for (int j = i+1; !found && j < studentIDNumber.size(); j++)
    {
        if (studentIDNumber.get(i).equals(studentIDNumber.get(j)))
        {
        found = true;
        count++;
        }
    }
}

return (studentIDNumber.size()-count);
}
public void toString(int studentID)// to String method 
 {
int rowNumber[]=new int[3];
int i = 0;
int highestMathScore = 0;
int highestVerbalScore = 0;
int bestTotalScore = 0;

    if(studentIDNumber.contains(studentID))
    {
        rowNumber[i] = studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID);

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {

            if(studentIDNumber.get(studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID) + j + 1 ) == studentID)
            {

                i++;
                rowNumber[i] = studentIDNumber.indexOf(studentID) + j + 1;                  
            }   


        }

        System.out.println("Evidence-Based Reading and Writing Section | Math Section | Total Score" );// Printing out the selected students scores
        for(i = 0; i < rowNumber.length; i++) 

        {
            if(rowNumber[i] >= 1 )

            {
                if(mathScore.get(rowNumber[i]) > highestMathScore)// if math score at  position i is greater than highest math score, than it is equal to that math score 
                {
                    highestMathScore = mathScore.get(rowNumber[i]);
                }
                if(verbalScore.get(rowNumber[i]) > highestVerbalScore)//if verbal score at position i is greater than highest verbal, than it is equal to that verbal score
                {
                    highestVerbalScore = verbalScore.get(rowNumber[i]);
                }
                if(totalScore.get(rowNumber[i]) > bestTotalScore)//if total score ar position i is greater than best total score, than it is equal to that score 
                {
                    bestTotalScore = totalScore.get(rowNumber[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(verbalScore.get(rowNumber[i]) + " | " + mathScore.get(rowNumber[i]) + " | " + totalScore.get(rowNumber[i]));
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Highest Math Score: " + highestMathScore);
        System.out.println("Highest Verbal Score: " + highestVerbalScore);
        System.out.println("Best Total Score: " + bestTotalScore);
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Student ID does not exist");
    }

 }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.